# Error using module commands with javac in java 9

Tags: java, javac

I am following examples from a book but i have an error when i try to save the code in a mods directory. When i type `javac -d mods --module-source-path src src\com.jdojo.intro\module-info.java src\com.jdojo.intro\com\jdojo\intro\Welcome.java` I have the error

```
javac: invalid flag: --module-source-path
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

The files are all in the correct directories.

Using *java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+180)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+180, mixed mode)*

Comment: Did you try it without the offending flag?

Comment: I think it might be because of the random src word between --module-source-path and the src folder after it, but I'm not sure since I haven't used Java 9 yet.

Comment: I tried without the 'src' after 'path' but i have the same error. The command is copy pasted from a book example.

Comment: Did you use `-help`? I'm pretty sure it gives you a list of possible options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check the compiler version being called:

```
javac -version
```

probably there is a previous installation being used. In that case adjust the `PATH` environment variable so the path to the Java 9 installation is a the very beginning of it. (or just use the full path when calling javac, like in `\some\dir\java\jdk9\bin\javac`)

I use the following batch file (windows) to change my environment to Java 9:

```
@set JAVA_HOME=%JDK9_HOME%
@PATH .;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
@java -version
```

having set `JDK9_HOME` to the directory where I installed java.

Comment: Yes, when i changed to java 9 i only changed JAVA_HOME from env variables but i left java 8 in the path, changing it solved the problem.